# Dividing by a binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is the following not allowed?

$$y(x+2)=2x+3.$$

Why can I not divide both terms on the right hand side by $x+2$ if I want to solve for $y$.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $y=\frac{2x}{x+2}+\frac{3}{x+2}$?

Comment: Yeah can I transform it to that?

Comment: Just wondering, who said it was not allowed in the first place?

Comment: I just remember hearing it. Glad to know I can do it.

Comment: OK cool thanks, I was just wondering about the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}$ is a solution only as long as $x\neq {-2}$.  Otherwise you risk a divide-by-zero error.

It's not that you cannot do it; it's that you must take *note* of such conditions and always *check* that your final solution doesn't involve a contradiction.  (That is, you cannot latter require $x={-2}$.)

Oh, and you cannot use it if $x={-2}$ is *already* a possible solution.

Comment: <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mi>y</mi>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <mfrac>
    <mrow>
      <mn>2</mn>
      <mi>x</mi>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
  </mfrac>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mfrac>
    <mn>3</mn>
    <mrow>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>+</mo>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
  </mfrac>
</math>

Comment: Yes, $y = \frac{2x}{x+2}+\frac{3}{x+2}$

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem dividing by $x+2$ here.

If $x=-2$, then the left-hand side is $0$ while the right-hand side is $-1$. So in any logical universe in which your equation is true, $x\neq -2$. Therefore you should feel fine dividing by $x+2$.

Comment: Can I write is as  y = (2x / x+2)+ (3 / (x+2))

Comment: @blairdavidson Mathrmatically it is the same thing. Now, if you are trying to get a computer to make a nice picture of the curve $y(x+2) = 2x+3$, then watch out. Computers don't always know mathematics. For example, Mathematica gives a nice ContourPlot of $y(x +2) = 2x+3$, but its Plot of $(2x+3)/(x+2)$ has an ugly glitch as $x = -2$. This, despite the fact that the set of all real pairs $(x, (2x+3)/(x +2))$ is the same as the set of all real pairs $(x,y)$ with $y(x +2) = 2x+3$.